# Pre-render as3 animation

Tags: actionscript-3

I need to pre render animation, which I am creating by code in as3. I would like to save every frame of _debugBmp to *.png or *.bmp file, or create sprite sheet.

Is that possible?

Thank you for answer.

```
public class PerlinNoise extends Sprite 
{
    // premenne pre perlin noise
    private var _baseX:Number = 45;
    private var _baseY:Number = 5;
    private var _numOctaves:uint = 3;
    private var _randomSeed:int = 50;
    private var _stitch:Boolean = true;
    private var _fractalNoise:Boolean = false;
    private var _channelOptions:uint = 1;
    private var _grayScale:Boolean = true;
    private var _offsets:Array = [];

    private var _perlinBitmapData : BitmapData;
    private var _debugBmp   : Bitmap;

    public function PerlinNoise() 
    {
        _perlinBitmapData = new BitmapData(275, 50, true);

        // oktavy perlin noisu
        for(var i:int = 0; i < _numOctaves;i++) _offsets[i] = new Point(0,0);

        _debugBmp = new Bitmap(_perlinBitmapData);
        addChild(_debugBmp);

        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
    }

    private function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void
    {   
        // animacia perlin noisu
        _offsets[1]['x'] += 1; // 2
        _offsets[1]['y'] += 1/4;//1/4

        // aplikacia perlin noisu
        _perlinBitmapData.perlinNoise(_baseX, _baseY, _numOctaves, _randomSeed, _stitch, _fractalNoise, _channelOptions, _grayScale, _offsets);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend putting your code in an Adobe AIR application and then save the BitMapData out to files after each image is created in the onEnterFrame method. Once you have al your images than you could make a spritesheet out of them.

Comment: how do I save BitMapData out to files ?